# Issue with generic Unit of Measures / match

Tags: f#

I have read quite a few ressources on Unit of Measures (including the good Microsoft Doc and f# for fun and profit) but I still cannot make my code work.

```
[<Measure>] type USD
[<Measure>] type JPY
[<Measure>] type EUR

type FxUnit<[<Measure>] 'u,[<Measure>] 'v> = {UnitRate : float<'u/'v>}

let getFx1 u  =
    match u with
    | "USD" -> {UnitRate = 1.0<USD/USD>}
    | "EUR" -> {UnitRate = 1.0<USD/EUR>}
```

This way I get an error under:

```
1.0<USD/EUR>
```

I have tried thse:

```
let getFx1  u : (float<'u>) =
let getFx1  u : (float<'u/'v>) =
```

without much success. It seems that with a match, I can't return some type FxUnit with different UoM.

Any idea how I could fix this?

thanks.

Comment: This seems to be consistent with the general usage of type parameters; for example, if you have a function returning a ``'a list``, you cannot return a ``float list`` from one branch and a ``int list`` from another branch. It *might* work if you declare your function ``getFx1`` as ``inline`` (as the compiler will then use statically resolved type parameters).

Comment: The thing with Unit of Measures is that they are a feature to let the compiler verify that your arithmetic logic is sound so you do not end up for instance adding `Yens + Euros`. For that to work you need to have values with specific UoMs. If they were to be generic then the compiler cannot help you anymore and they lose their usefulness. So, there are very few things you can do with generic UoMs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to define a function that takes a string and returns a value of type either `FxUnit<USD,USD>` or `FxUnit<USD,EUR>`. A function can't have two different return types, decided at runtime.

You could make FxUnit take two values of a discriminated union instead of measures:

```
type Currency =
    | USD
    | JPY
    | EUR

type FxUnit = { UnitRate : float; From : Currency; To : Currency }

let getFx1 u  =
    match u with
    | "USD" -> {UnitRate = 1.0; From = USD; To = USD}
    | "EUR" -> {UnitRate = 1.0; From = USD; To = EUR}
    | _     -> failwithf "Unrecognised units %s" u
```